# Can I hand pollinate a single aloe vera plant?

Tags: flowers

I was wondering if i can simply pollinate one aloe Vera plant myself?

I've checked the web but i found one video on YouTube where he has a lot of aloe plants and I wasn't sure if i needed two kinds of plants (male\female)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aloe vera is monoecious, meaning male and female parts of the flowers are present in each plant. However, there is another problem if you only have one plant; the flowers are what's known as protandrous, which means the stamen releases pollen before the stigma is ready to receive it. You might be able to do it if you have more than one flower, by attempting to collect the pollen from a newer flower and placing that on a stigma from an older flower, in hopes it is now receptive, but it might not work, not sure. Info here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/aloe-vera-self-pollinate-85089.html

Comment: do you think that gathering, waiting and then polinating ,is a good solution?

Comment: That is another strategy I've seen work. Use a qtip to gather the pollen and store it in a plastic bag.

Comment: Whether that will work is down to how fresh you can keep the pollen - what you really need is one of those swabs that come in a long tube for medical use when they want samples - the tube might keep the pollen fresh, without it getting all over the inside of a plastic bag. No idea if it would work though...

Comment: ok, thanks mate :)